# Image attachment as part of DTO or separate upload (ASP.NET MVC 2 & WCF REST)

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, wcf-rest

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 2 client application that consumes a RESTful WCF service application for data persistence. A new requirement has come up to support an image attached/associated to one of my existing domain objects (Product).

Currently, the client application calls the service to obtain a list of Products (in the form of a list of lightweight ProductInfo objects) and displays the list to the user.  When the user clicks an item in the list, the client calls the service to get the specific Product object which supports editing by the user.  When saved, the client posts the updated Product to the service for persistence.

The new requirement calls for me to display the associated image in the list as well as allow the user to set/replace the image when editing the Product.  The current image is also displayed in the Product editor.  Only one image will be associated with each Product and the image will be required.

1. Is Stream the best way to pass the image data between client and server or should I go with Byte[]?
2. For the list, would it be wise to add a new Image property to ProductInfo of type Stream (or Byte[]) or require a separate call to the service to download the image?
3. Likewise for editing, do I just treat the image data as any other property and pass it back and forth across the wire using an Image property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I appreciate Darin's response and originally headed down that path, I ended up going with the same approach outlined in [Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework](http://books.google.com/books?id=lfPkn31fpNQC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=asp.net%20mvc%202%20add%20product%20upload%20image&source=bl&ots=B_W8H3Q1rj&sig=_PxmdNfikjFVSfrUA2cPzO1myf4&hl=en&ei=NbrTTdeYBIiitgeP7dGvCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CHYQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=asp.net%20mvc%202%20add%20product%20upload%20image&f=false).

Chapter 6 describes how an image can be uploaded as part of the edit page for a Product object then displayed using a controller action in another page.  The only difference in my application is that persistence is handled in a different tier via a RESTful web service interface.  However, based on the approach shown in the book, I decided to go with a single DTO that contains properties for the binary image data and string MIME type information.

If I had a different UI or a heavier object to pass around, I would definitely reconsider this approach but for me, this time around, this works great.

Answer (score 1):

> Is Stream the best way to pass the image data between client and server or should I go with Byte[]?

This will depend on the binding you are using but with SOAP even if you choose Stream eventually when the serializer needs to send it over the wire it will be a base64 encoded byte array.

> For the list, would it be wise to add a new Image property to ProductInfo of type Stream (or Byte[]) or require a separate call to the service to download the image?

I would go with a separate call to download each image given a product id. This way you won't be downloading images every time you want to view product info without previews which could save bandwidth.

Another possibility is to load all the images at one go from the WCF service and then invoke the controller action that will download them using AJAX. Then embed them in the HTML as base64 data (the way Google does with image previews in the results page)

> Likewise for editing, do I just treat the image data as any other property and pass it back and forth across the wire using an Image property?

For editing you could have a service method which will take the byte array and the id of the item you are updating.

Comment: I am using a WCF REST service, so webHttpBinding which does not use SOAP.

Comment: My concern with having separate service methods when editing a Product is that I'll have 1 call to retrieve the Product details & another to get the image, display them to the user, let them make changes to, let's say, the product description & image, then submit the changes back to the service in one operation to update the description & another to update the image. That's 4 service calls for 2 operations (Get and Update). Is that really the best way to handle it? Better put, is there something wrong with including the image data with the other properties when getting & sending the Product?

Comment: @SonOfPirate, if you include the image data as part of the product (a `byte[]`) how do you intend to display it in the HTML? After all the `<img>` expects its `src` property to point either to a server action that will return the image data or inline base64 encoded.

Comment: Good question. My first thoughts are that I would return a FileResult (using the File method in the Controller class) from a ProductImage action method. But this would mean that I'd have to preserve the original object in Session or something to support the second call to render the image. Hmmm...